# C++ non-type template parameters: Is typedef of an integral type an integral type?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, typedef

I know I can do function template `template<int N> void f () {}`.

But what about `template<std::size_t N> void f() {}`?

Comment: Typedefs do not make new types.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, so this should work?

Comment: Yes, it should "work". A `typedef` is an alias for a type. So a `typedef` of a certain integral type *is* that very same integral type.

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type so the two definitions you've got there are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `typedef` is just an alias for the given type.  So any `typedef` of an integral type is itself an integral type.  And types don't get any more integral than `std::size_t`.

Comment: @ZacHowland: Are you saying that `int`, `short`, and `long`, are somehow "more integral" than `std::size_t`?

Comment: @KeithThompson:  Not necessarily "more integral", but they would at least equivalently integral to `std::size_t`.

Comment: @ZacHowland: Exactly. A type is either integral or not, and the last sentence of the answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: @KeithThompson:  Hence the ;) at the end of my original comment and the first up-vote on the answer ...